# Uncertain about some Python generator syntax

Tags: python

I would like to understand some Python code that I've been reading:

```py
my_stream = some.library.method(arg1=val, arg2=val)(input_stream)
```

My guess is that `some.library.method()` returns an iterator into which `input_stream` is passed as an argument. Is this correct?

I have searched "python generator functions" to get documentation on this type of syntax but have found nothing other than nested examples such as: `sum(mult(input))`. Can anyone provide an explanation or link?

### UPDATE

Below is a specific example:

```py
tokenized_train_stream = trax.data.Tokenize(vocab_file=VOCAB_FILE, vocab_dir=VOCAB_DIR)(train_stream)
```

Comment: An iterator isn't callable. `some.library.method(arg1=val, arg2=val) ` returns a function, or some other callable object, which you then call with `input_stream`. Without any context that's all we can say.

Comment: `some.library.method(arg1=val, arg2=val)` could be returning a Class or a method. If it is a class then it is getting instantiated with `input_stream`. If it is returning a method then that method is being called with `input_stream` argument.

Comment: why not think method as a function that returns a delegate/func(since you're faimiliar with C#)

Comment: There's no reason to believe `some.library.method(arg1=vale, arg2=val)` returns an *iterator*. Instead, this implies the result *callable*, since the result is *called*. Iterators generally aren't callable, although, you are free to define a callable iterator. Generators, a specific kind of iterator, are definitely not callable though

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have been reading about *callable* objects in Python and *decorators*. This has helped my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

*Is this correct?*

If you are unsure about if thing in `python` is something you might use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) built-in module, it provides numerous `is`*something* functions, among them `isgenerator`, simple usage example

```
import inspect
lst = [1,2,3]
gen = (i for i in [1,2,3])
print(inspect.isgenerator(lst))  # False
print(inspect.isgenerator(gen))  # True
```